# Crop a string using sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, text-processing

I have a command that outputs me a list with the following pattern

```
exp_70_T8_s1
exp_71_T8_s5
exp_72_T8_s10
exp_73_T10_s1
exp_74_T10_s5
exp_75_T10_s10
...
```

How can I get the numbers after "_T" and "_s" respectively using `sed` or something similar in bash?
The output should look like this

```
8
8
8
10
10
10
```

and

```
1
5
10
1
5
10
```

for `_T` and `_s` respectively

The first part of my command looks like this:

```
for f in $(find . -name "someFile.txt" | sort); do echo $f; done | grep /someFolderName/
```

Basically I would like to add the command to the one given above.

Comment: How should the output look like? `81`, `85`, `810`...? Else?

Comment: Oh. Sorry the output should look like `8`, `8`, `8`, `10`,... I will add that to the question.

Comment: (1) `find . -name "someFile.txt"` doesn’t make sense; I presume that you are really doing `find . -name "exp_*_T*_s*"` or something similar.  (2) `for f in $(find … | sort); do echo $f; done` is awkward and unreliable; is there a problem with just doing `find … | sort`?  (3) I’m curious as to why you would need `find ` **`. `** `… | grep /someFolderName/`.  Check whether `find someFolderName …` does what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sed` with pattern grouping to capture the desired portions:

```
your_command | sed -r 's/.*_T([0-9]+)_s([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/'
```

- `([0-9]+)` is the first captured group, `[0-9]` matches any number between `0-9` and `+` indicates one or more match of the preceding token `[0-9]` in this case
- `([0-9]+)` is the second captured group
- In the replacement pattern the two captured groups are referenced by `\1` and `\2` respectively.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
exp_70_T8_s1
exp_71_T8_s5
exp_72_T8_s10
exp_73_T10_s1
exp_74_T10_s5
exp_75_T10_s10

$ sed -r 's/.*_T([0-9]+)_s([0-9]+)/\1 \2/' file.txt 
8 1
8 5
8 10
10 1
10 5
10 10
```

---

Change the replacement pattern to meet your need, for example without any space:

```
your_command | sed -r 's/.*_T([0-9]+)_s([0-9]+)/\1\2/' file.txt
```

---

**Answer to the edited question:**

For `_T`:

```
your_command | grep -Po '.*_T\K\d+'    ## Using grep
your_command | sed -r 's/.*_T([0-9]+).*/\1/'   ## Using sed
```

For `_s`:

```
your_command | grep -Po '.*_s\K\d+$'    ## Using grep
your_command | sed -r 's/.*_s([0-9]+)$/\1/'    # Using sed
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot :). I assume `\1` and `\2` means the first and second hit.  Can you explain what the `+` sign means in that command?

Comment: @mcExchange Check my edits..

Answer (score 5):

Using AWK:

```bsh
command | awk -F_T\|_s '{print $2}'
```

```bsh
command |
    awk -F_T\|_s '
        {
            print $2
        }
    '
```

and:

```bsh
command | awk -F_T\|_s '{print $3}'
```

```bsh
command |
    awk -F_T\|_s '
        {
            print $3
        }
    '
```

Where `command` is the command that outputs the file.

- `-F_T\|_s`: sets `_T` and `_s` as input field separators;
- `{print $2}`: prints the 2nd field.
- `{print $N}`: prints the 3rd field.

```
% cat file
exp_70_T8_s1
exp_71_T8_s5
exp_72_T8_s10
exp_73_T10_s1
exp_74_T10_s5
exp_75_T10_s10
% cat file | awk -F_T\|_s '{print $2}'
8
8
8
10
10
10
% cat file | awk -F_T\|_s '{print $3}'
1
5
10
1
5
10
```

Comment: This works also nicely. Good explanation. Thank you

Comment: Looks very elegant!